# Is it possible to do ps -aux with .net core c#?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, terminal, .net-core

Recently I am running some applications on an ubuntu linux host with c# .net core and was wondering if there is some way to reach the content of a linux terminal command? Specifically search the

```
ps -aux
```

in this case.
Thanks.

Edit: because this question for some reason received down votes the stackoverflow algorithm decided to restrict me from posting questions and it says that I should improve my current ones.
Not quite sure what that means in this particular case but I wanted to add up to the question that I needed this information in order to use C# with .net core as a scripting language and monitor some remotely run processes and
send alarms if a process is down for some reason. I found better ways to do it but still answer may be useful to some people.

Comment: `Process.GetProcesses();` ?

Comment: You can pipe the output of `ps -aux` into your program. That is more in line with the Unix philosophy.

Comment: @L.B thanks! Actually it works fine now! Please post it as an answer

Comment: @Romoku how do I call ps -aux > file from code?

Comment: You will use the Unix pipe `|`. So using something like `ps aux | dotnet yourprogram.dll` in the terminal. You can read the output of `ps aux` from standard input.

Comment: @Romoku I am getting 0 length args[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting external processes and read the output of them, you can use [`Process.GetProcesses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you really have to use some external processes (writing to console, like `ls | myapp`) you can use *standard input* to read the text

Ex:

```
var input = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput()).ReadToEnd();
```

See also: [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx)